# How to mouse over and click on " Mobiles section"

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

To move to Electronics menu:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[text()='Electronics']"))).build().perform();
```

To move Mobile Menu:

```
//WebElement mobile = (new WebDriverWait(driver,2)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[1][text]()='Mobiles')")));
```

To click on the Mobiles:

```
// action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[1][text]()='Mobiles')"))).click();

WebElement mobile=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[1][text]()='Mobiles')"));
mobile.click();
```

Tried the above code but didn't work error message displayed:

> Xpath does not exist

Comment: can you give the html DOM highlighting the element to whci we need to do mouse hover?

Comment: Hi its a https://www.flipkart.com/               application

Answer (score 1):

We can use this xpath for the mobile element:

```
//a[@title='Electronics']
```

complete code to do mouse hover:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Electronics']"))).click().build().perform();
//Clicking on the mobile tab
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@title='Mobiles']")).click();
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi this takes me to the mobile accesories page  need to get this page https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles?otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobiles      Electronic(hover)-> below electronic theres is option called " Mobiles"

Comment: ur code takes me to a diffrent page    https://www.flipkart.com/mobile-accessories/pr?sid=tyy,4mr&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mobile%20Accessories

Comment: See first i need to hover on " Electronics" then the sub menu are visible and then " Mobiles" that id displayed just below " Electronics"

Comment: This works fine ,do u use any tool to find unique xpath or any element? pls suggest some tools

Comment: @Jagaur I have used chrome dev tools to write the xpath. Kindly accept this as answer if this helped you. Thanks.